# D3 map as black box

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I've downloaded a shapefile of the Spanish provinces from the website of the Spanish Ministry of Agriculture:

http://servicios2.marm.es/sia/visualizacion/descargas/mapas.jsp

Then I've used mapshaper, with "repairing points" and exporting it as shapefile.

Next, I've put the .shp and the .shx files in a folder, with the original .dbf and I've converted it to json with ogr2ogr, exactly as Scott Murray explains in his book. http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch12.html

The result is not a map, but a black box:
http://bl.ocks.org/murtra/raw/6150452a9ecca742e95c/

I can't understand why, because the GeoJSON has the same structure as other shapefiles I've used before, and if I inspect the svg, the paths are there. I've tried with another projections/scales, but nothing changes... any idea?

NOTE: changing the provincias.json by ESP_adm2.json (downloaded from http://www.gadm.org/country), the map works. All the files can be found here: https://gist.github.com/murtra/6150452a9ecca742e95c

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you're seeing black boxes because of the specific way your shapes are encoded.

Try changing the styles of drawn paths for "fill" and "stroke" to none and black.

Hope this helps,
ioniATX

Answer (score 0):

My issue was due to having an `id` `attr` mentioned instead of a `class`. Could be a similar issue:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this.topo = await this._geoService.getUSTopoJson();
    const projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa().scale(1070).translate([ this._width / 2, this._height / 2 ]);
    const path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
    this._svg = d3.select('svg')
      .attr('width', this._width)
      .attr('height', this._height);

    this._svg.append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'background')
      .attr('width', this._width)
      .attr('height', this._height);

    const g = this._svg.append('g');

    g.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'states') // <-- Needed to be 'class' instead of 'id'
      .selectAll('path')
      .data(topojson.feature(this.topo, this.topo.objects.states).features)
      .enter().append('path')
      .attr('d', path);

    g.append('path')
      .datum(topojson.mesh(this.topo, this.topo.objects.states, (a, b) => a !== b ))
      .attr('id', 'state-borders')
      .attr('d', path);
  }
```